# Calling C# code from Java?

Tags: c#, java, java-native-interface

Does anyone have a good solution for integrating some C# code into a java application?

The code is small, so I could re-write in java, but I would rather reuse the code if possible. Don't repeat yourself, etc.

Also, I know I can expose the C# as a web service or whatever, but it has some security/encryption stuff in there, so I would rather keep it tightly integrated if possible.

---

Edit: It's going to be on a server-based app, so "downloading" another runtime is irrelevant.

Comment: If its Server Based, what is the platform? I have no idea how well things like COM interop work with Mono, so that's another factor to consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an IL to Java Bytecode compiler [GrassHopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130) which may be of use to you.  I've never tried it though.

I'd look at rewriting your code in Java though

EDIT: Note that Grasshopper seems to be no longer available.

Comment: The Grass hopper link is broken.

Comment: Probably no longer available

Answer (score 33):

You would use the Java Native Interface to call your C# code compiled into a DLL.

If its a small amount of C#, it would be much easier to port it to Java. If its a lot, this might be a good way to do it.

Here is a highlevel overview of it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Your other option would be to create a COM assembly from the C# code and use J-Interop to invoke it.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-interop/

Answer (score 22):

I am author of [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net/), open source intraprocess bridge between JVM and CLR. It's build on top of JNI and PInvoke. No C/C++ code needed. I hope it will help you.

Comment: That looks pretty cool, did you ever find a way to support both Linux and Windows?

Answer (score 7):

If it's short, I think you're better off re-writing the code in java.  Downloading one 50Mb runtime is bad enough.

Answer (score 3):

We used [JNBridge](http://jnbridge.com) for this, and it worked great.  It handles Java->.NET and vice versa, all in-proc.

Comment: Yes, this is a commercial product.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to rewrite hadle it as an [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) and choose one of following:

- Named pipes
- Sockets
- SOAP

Answer (score 1):

You can call your c# classes (compiled in a dll) via a bridging library, various libraries are available, every one with his characteristics. **JNBridge** generate proxy classes that you can call to manage the code in java classes. **JCOBridge** let you load your c# classes and use it from java using the invoke mechanism, also **javonet** let you import java classes and call java code using the invoke mechanism. 
All the explored solutions are commercial solutions that let you call java code from .NET and vice-versa with graphical user interface integration and other amenities.

**Links**:
[jnbridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/) java-.NET bridge Developer and Deployment license schema with 30 day free trial
[jcobridge](https://www.jcobridge.com) java-.NET bridge Developer and Deployment license schema with unlimited Trial
[javonet](https://www.javonet.com/) java-.NET bridge Research and Professional license schema with 30-day unlimited Trial after sign-up

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it if it's not too much trouble.
The web service would work, but it seems like that would be a lot of overhead just to reuse a little code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.infoq.com/articles/in-process-java-net-integration suggests running CLR and JVM in the same process space and passing calls back and forth. It sounds very efficient. I'm going to give it a try and integrate it into [Jace](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jace/) if it works well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a piece of code that is exposable as a command line utility, I just make the other host language use a system call to execute the utility.

If your C# app needs to call Java, compile a special Java main that takes appropriate command line args and returns text output.

It the oldest, simplest method.