# can use a library created in vb.net or c# in java?

Tags: c#, java, vb.net

I have written some classes in C# and compiled it. Now I have the library file for these classes. Can I use the same dll with Java?

I do not want to write it in Java once again because I am writing the same program in different languages (trying to do so).

So I am making the classes to a library file and want to use it in all the programing languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java normally uses a completely different runtime (inside the JVM). There *are* tools intending to help bridge the gap ([IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) leaps to mind), but *in general*: no, you can't do this. Of course, you can use IPC etc to talk *between* them, but they are **not** best friends.

Answer (score 1):

One area you can look into is JNI (Java Native Interface), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface as a starting point. There are possibly easier to use bridges for .NET to Java, ah here we go, see [Calling C# code from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398/calling-c-code-from-java)

Answer (score 1):

You need to searialize your code into byte, xml or json. so you can use your codes in another language

Comment: "searialize your code into byte, xml or json"  ? how to serialize a C# function into json