# Call C# dll from a Java Application

Tags: c#, java, .net, dll

I have a dll created in c# which does some database operation upon calling. I have to pass few parameters from a Java application to a method in the dll. Any Idea on how to do this.

OR

Any better ideas for calling a method in c# by a java application?

Thanks

Edit : My java application is a standard Dialogue Designer application from AVAYA Platform and I have developed a C# application which works on a SDK for .net only. So i need data to be passed from java application to .net application

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398/calling-c-sharp-code-from-java

Comment: @tafa : I saw that question which you're referring . Plz see the edit, my requirement is completely different

Comment: Could you possibly pass the data via a TCP connection? Just get the DLL to listen on a local port and get the java application to send data from that same port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this a while back although I enver got far with it as the requirements changed. But I did read that using JNI, Java Native Interface may be able to help you with what you are needing to do.

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework. It includes the following components:

- A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
- A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries
- **Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability**

The third point is maybe what you are looking for.

Project Site here:  http://www.ikvm.net/

Comment: My java application is a standard Dialogue Designer application from AVAYA and I have developed a C# application which works on a SDK for .net only. So i need data to be passed from java application to .net application