# Can Java inject DLL in another process?

Tags: java, jna, dll-injection

I've actually already asked questions regarding my problem. To prevent people asking for *irrelevant* details *over again*, I'll post this background info you can skip:

> I'm making a automation application. This application does some tasks
>   for the user over time for specific window. When these taks are
>   required to be made, window flashes in taskbar and sometimes even
>   steals focus to get the user to do the task. Once the automation is
>   here, this is no longer wanted - the user will only focus the window
>   when he wants to check how well is the automation doing it's job.
>
> I discovered this [focus and flash disable dll](http://code.google.com/p/annoyance/) project thanks to this [superuser post about applications stealing focus](https://superuser.com/a/404246/194976).

My automation application is in Java. So while I can open a DLL injection application and disable flashing manually, I'd like to integrate it in the java applicaton - for example as a setting option. When user selects to disable flashing and stealing focus, the dll will be injected.

Of course, this requires Java to be able to inject my `.dll` file. I've found this project: [`dotnet-dll-injector`](https://github.com/sarxos/dotnet-dll-injector) but it only deals with .NET dll files.

**Q:** Is there a way, in Java, to pick a `.dll` file and inject it into process? Which libraries would lead to this if the solution isn't straightforward?

I've noticed `CreateRemoteThread` is somehow related to the DLL injection. Maybe JNA library supports that?

Comment: If you call C code via JNI you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Might be simplistic, but what about plain ol' `System.load();`?

Comment: @Radiodef sure, I could make another DLL to call that would inject my DLL's. But that's getting quite complicated and my user's might not like how non-transparent my program is.

Comment: @user489041 No, that function is designed to load java libraries into Java program. I want to load binary DL library into "binary" process.

Comment: Expanding on my idea, have a C wrapper that you load using System.load() that exposes the api you need.

Comment: I already took a look if there's a DLL injector C/C++ opensource project I could compile as dll. Unfortunatelly, I've found nothing. However your solution seems like the right one - only have the necessary native code in dll, do the rest in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it natively in Java.

Since you've found a working solution in .NET and your task is Windows-specific, I suggest the following:

Build dotnet-dll-injector as a DLL and call it from your Java app.  [How to call into .NET dll from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743715/how-to-call-into-net-dll-from-java)

Edit: easier to build it as a console app and use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");`

Or if you're still early in the development process and you have no immediate plan to go cross-platform, just do everything in C# and save some headache.

Comment: From my understanding, dotnet-dll-injector is Java software developped to inject `.NET` dll's. That means it cannot probably inject normal binary DLL files. Using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` I could bundle this [DLL injector tool](http://securityxploded.com/remote-dll-injector.php) with the project. But I didn't want to distribute 3rd party binary file - the DLL I'm using is suspicious enough. I want my project to be transparent as much as possible - I'm distributing in gaming environment where keyloggers and viruses are everywhere and people are rightfully paranoid.