# Call C# dll from Java on Google App Engine

Tags: c#, java, .net, google-app-engine

Does anyone know if it's possible to invoke C# methods/classes (from a dll) in a Google App Engine Java app (server side)? If it's possible, do you have any idea how it could be achieved?

EDIT - Any other variants beside using web services?

EDIT 2 - This question is specific to the Google App Engine environment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992684/call-c-sharp-dll-from-a-java-application

Comment: @JunedAhsan not related, GAE works on Google servers... I bet they do not want JNI there

Comment: @Amber Could you elaborate on that a little bit more?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I've heard about JNI, but I was interested specifically in GAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Each python, java, go and now PHP runtime has a list of directly supported libraries that might have binary file dependancies.  e.g. The python runtime has support for Numpy, PIL, PyCrypto  and a few others https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Java has a whitelist of aceptable base/core classes, upon which everything else is built.  You can include your own jars, but only if the call whitelisted classes when trying to interact with the machine, network etc... - ie there are no GUI classes (like swing).

You can't just upload and call some arbitrary binary object, in your case a windows DLL, or some linux shared library.  One of appengines strengths in fact is the secure sandbox.

Some basic reading of the introduction to appengine docs for any of the runtimes will give you a feel for what you can and can't do.   The environment is changing over time, until recently you couldn't make outbound socket calls.  I seriously doubt however you will be able to ever just install/run some abritrary binary object that has been built for some other platform.)

Answer (score 2):

While not a GAE specialist, I do believe you may be able to access C# methods if they are exposed as a WebService.

Here´s a post about how to do it via Python:
http://www.bloing.net/2011/01/soap-webservice-gae-python-howto/

And here, how to create a c# WebService:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863/Your-first-C-Web-Service

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was interested if there is a possibility to invoke it directly on the server.

Comment: Ah, i see. I didn't knew that was a prerequisite. Hope you find a viable answer - and let me suggest to mention that prereq on your post.