# how to call methods from a c# dll in java?

Tags: java, dll

I've created a c# dll in visual studio 2008

the content of the c# dll is as given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace hello
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static double addUp(double number, double Number)
        {
            return number + Number;
        }
        public static double minus(double number, double Number)
        {
            return number - Number;
        }
    }
}
```

and through java i've loaded the hello.dll using

> **System.loadLibrary("hello");**

The java code is as given below:

```
package pkgnew;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class check 
{

    public static native double addUp(double number,double Number);
    static 
    {
      try
      {
      System.loadLibrary("hello");
      System.out.println("SUCCESS");
      }catch(Exception ex){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Required DLLs Not Found\n"+ex.getCause(),"Error Loading Libraries", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
          new check().getval();
    }

    public void getval() {
        try
        {
       double g=this.addUp(52.2, 51.3);
        }catch(Exception y){System.out.println("ERROR IS:"+y);}
    }
}
```

but the problem is that i'm getting output as:

**OUTPUT**

```
SUCCESS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: pkgnew.check.addUp(DD)D
    at pkgnew.check.addUp(Native Method)
    at pkgnew.check.getval(check.java:35)
    at pkgnew.check.main(check.java:29)
Java Result: 1
```

Can anyone tell me why i'm getting this error....and why i'm not able to call the dll methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can call native extensions in Java without using JNI wrappers (or at least some library which translates to JNI under the hood). Have you tried out the frameworks/suggestions mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398/calling-c-sharp-code-from-java)?

Comment: Did you have a look at that thread? There is one free and one paid library mentioned which you might want to look into. Also, if you want to go the pure JNI way, google for JNI tutorials to get started.

Comment: Take a look at this one here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/javacsharp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call C# dll in Java. There is a workaround. You'll have to first write a C++ managed class for C# code then create a of C++ dll and use it in java.

[This link might be helpful.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/javacsharp.aspx)