# Calling a .net method from java - method matching

Tags: java, .net, dll

I have a java program which is suppose to call a .net program in a dll file. So far this is what I have done:

```
static{
    System.loadlibrary("libraryname")
}

native String   EncryptPassword(Object object);
```

I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when I call the native method. I think its likely in the method matching to the .net method. The .net method is defined like this:

```
PasswordEncyptor.EncryptController.EncryptPassword(PasswordEncryptor.EncryptController.EncryptionRules)
```

We weren't given the code, only specifications document defining the methods in the dll. I'm not sure how can I create a native method to match that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling C# code from Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398/calling-c-sharp-code-from-java)

Comment: Recoding the .net methods to java is not an option since the dll is from a third party