# Is it possible to invoke a .NET Core app in Java?

Tags: java, c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core (console) app that I would like for a Java app to depend on. Essentially I would like to be able for the Java app to invoke a multi variable method in the .NET Core app and then pass the result back to the Java app. It would be nice if the .NET Core app could be embedded in the Java app. I have previously seen .NET Framework specific solutions to this problem, but since this would only be relevant on Windows, I would like a solution that also works on Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling C# code from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398/calling-c-sharp-code-from-java)

Comment: @vinicius.ras: No, this is not a duplicate. The questions you refer to, consider .NET Framework (and not .NET Core). I would like for a multi platform solution.

Comment: WHY do you want to do this.

Comment: You can't "embed" an app in an app. Is your console app a utility or a service? If it's a utility you can invoke it by calling out to the OS and receive the output. If it's a service it needs to expose an interface so you can call that with your choice of RPC.

Comment: @iakobski: Could you describe or reference material that describes the utility and service approaches? My motivation is that I would like to be able to use a specific .NET library in my Java app.

Comment: Do you own the .net (core) app and/or able to make changes to it?

Comment: Yes, I own the app

Comment: @Birdie Provide this additional info as edits to your Question.

Answer (score 1):

In the past there were some technologies such as IKVM.NET and COM Interop wrappers but the former is defunct and the latter probably wouldn't work on Linux.

Since you own the .net core code, I would take a more modern microservice approach.  I would design the .net core app to be a REST API  running as a console app listening on a port.    I'd have the Java application spin up the   console app,  invoke the methods passing JSON back and forth and then spit it down when complete.

Comment: Thank you! I was considering doing that, but my fear was that it would be considered bad practise or expensive in terms of performance. Do you have a view on that?

Comment: Is it considered a typical microservice approach to expose the service through a REST API? And why is it considered “modern”?

Comment: It shouldn't take much code to mock it up and measure the performance.

Answer (score 0):

From my actual knowledge this nuget package [JCOBridge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JCOBridge/) is able to do what you are asking for.
Until now it supports linux for x64 architecture.
I tried the templates available on [Templates](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JCOBridge.Examples.Templates/) and them works on my Ubuntu 18.04. The same templates works on Windows.